# What happens if a permission is declared in several manifests?

Tags: android, android-permissions

In a short period of time I've come across two cases where different components/apps declare the same permission, i.e. by doing:

```
<permission android:name="com.company.A_PERMISSION" android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```

It's worth mentioning that the components in this case are all system apps. I suppose the reasoning in this case is that if one of the components is missing, at least the permission gets declared in the other.

Are there any side effects to declaring permissions in multiple locations?

Comment: i am totally unsure about your question does an app have multiple manifest file to declare permission??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suppose the reasoning in this case is that if one of the components is missing, at least the permission gets declared in the other.

Correct. While perhaps not relevant in your case, one example where this is used is for an SDK.

Let's suppose that Twitter opened up an SDK to work with their Android app, and it required a custom permission. Let's further suppose that they want their Vine app to use this SDK. However, the user could install those apps in any order (Twitter, then Vine; or Vine, then Twitter). If the user installs Vine first, and it requests a custom permission that does not exist, it does not get the permission, and therefore is screwed when it tries to use the Twitter SDK later on, after Twitter has been installed. By defining the custom permission in both Twitter and Vine apps, Vine is assured that the permission exists for its `<uses-permission>` element, and therefore it can obtain that permission (assuming the `android:protectionLevel` constraints are met).

> Are there any side effects to declaring permissions in multiple locations?

Well, an issue with using *any* custom permissions is that [somebody else might define it first, perhaps for nefarious ends](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).